# Choosing algorithms and/or data structures at runtime based on input characteristics

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, runtime-analysis, compilers

I've been reading about [Adaptive Computing](https://norvig.com/adapaper-pcai.html), i.e. the idea of computer programs taking feedback from the environment at runtime to improve the output in some way. More precisely, my current focus is in Self-Optimization: how to write programs that are able to choose the best algorithm/data structure in response to changes in the input profile. In the lower end, simple heuristics are used to apply specific algorithms in special cases, eg. Tim/Quick/MergeSort using Insertion Sort (which is $O(n^2)$) when the partition size is below a certain threshold. On the other extreme we have JIT compilers that optimize/deoptimize the code at runtime according to certain metrics.

However, I haven't found so far any examples of "high-level" decisions, like automatically choosing between two distinct implementations of an algorithm or a data structure at runtime. For example, think about a `AdaptiveList` object with the usual operations (`add,remove...`) and a array-backed storage. If the program keeps inserting elements in the middle of the list (which requires moving a lot of data to free space for the new element), the `AdaptiveList` may choose to move the data out of the array into a linked list. If the usage pattern changes again, the `AdaptiveList` may decide to go back to the array storage.

The closest thing I've been able to find (other than JIT compilers, of course) are projects like [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) and [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) where 
the code generation/algorithm selection is done *a priori* and never revisited. Maybe I'm the first one to entertain such fantasies, but I doubt it. Are you aware of other papers/projects that have investigated this idea?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Query optimizers for relational databases do something like this all the time.

Comment: One example may be MongoDB, which, as far as I have heard, dynamically creates indexes when it considers them useful.
Myself, I have done this on a smaller scale for my [PH-Tree project](http://www.phtree.org), a multi-dimensional index. During index creation, it chooses between 3 different implementations, depending on the dimensionality. Internally it has some (in-hindsight-not-to-be-proud-of-)micro-optimisations: It uses linear search instead of binary search if an array has less than 10 elements. It also uses for-loops instead of System.arrayCopy if it copies less than 7 elements.

Comment: I just remembered [liboil](https://liboil.freedesktop.org/wiki/) (Library for Optimized Inner Loops) for C/C++. If I remember correctly, when linked, it runs are very short benchmark at startup to determine which types of loops (for-loops etc) run fastest on the current CPU. Actual loops in your program then use the fastest implementation when a (accordingly marked) loop is executed. Someone told me this is now standard in GCC, but I could find no reference to support this. This is a bit like JIT.

Comment: There is also a large research body on _adaptive_ _databases_, which may be interesting.